# Error while edit the name in the account?

Tags: apex, visualforce, person-accounts

Hello all delegates Help me out i am having this error in my account object ..

> Upsert failed. First exception on row 0 with id 0019000001AUlnEAAT;
>   first error: INVALID_FIELD_FOR_INSERT_UPDATE, Account: bad field names
>   on insert/update call: Name: [Name]

Comment: What are you trying to do? where are you getting the error? Provide some details and if it involves code, provide it as well.

Comment: @MahmoodButt actually i am trying to updating the last name  in account and its showing an error.

Comment: Ok. From the error it appears you're using apex code/controller. Please share the code as well.

Comment: Do you have Person Accounts turned on? (See e.g. https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/ForumsMain?id=906F000000091HYIAY or http://www.pervasive.com/solutions/DataSynchforQuickBooksSalesforce/Troubleshooting/100016.aspx).

Comment: @KeithC  yes i am using person account .. and trying to update the last name and mobile number along with email Address also.  i having tried  the link that you provide me but its again showing me an error..

Comment: Posting your code will help other developers help solve your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For PersonAccounts you should not use **"Name"** instead use **FirstName** and **LastName**... PersonAccount is a blend of Account and contact. If it is a Business Account you should be using Name because on business Accounts you cannot Access firstName and LastName.

Cheers,